# jQuery click function to remove attribute from element and reinstate attribute on separate click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have elements on an SVG canvas which can be coloured according to a palette. I am trying to add a no fill option if a particular colour is clicked, and then remove that attribute if any other colour is selected.

js code:

```
if(!$selectedElems){return;}                                                                                

$selectedElems.each(function(){

$(this)[($(this).prop('tagName') === 'g' ? 'find' : 'filter')]('text[fill],rect[fill],circle,path').attr('fill',colour);

var $noFillColour =     $('#mainToolFill div.toolPopup a.color15');
var $otherColour =      $('#mainToolFill div.toolPopup a:not("color15")');

if($($noFillColour).bind('click')) {
    alert ($noFillColour);
    $selectedElems.attr('fill-opacity', '0');
}else{
  ($($otherColour).bind('click'));
    alert ($otherColour);
    $selectedElems.removeAttr('fill-opacity');
}
```

I suspect there is a problem with the variable. As I am seeing Object object in the alert. The first event is firing, so the fill-opacity is being applied to the selected elements, but this is regardless of which colour is picked. And clicking another colour will bot remove the fill-opacity attribute.

I also wondered if there was something wrong with the :not selector. I have also tried:

```
var $otherColour = $('#mainToolFill div.toolPopup a').not('#mainToolFill div.toolPopup a.color15');
```

If anyone can throw some light on this it would be appreciated. I note that this might not be the most economical way to implement this.

If you need to see more code let me know.

Comment: Is that code run every time you update your attributes, or only on load? Also, why are you nesting jQuery objects in your conditional, and what exactly is that conditional meant to do (if it is meant to bind to elements with different attributes, the selectors do that already)?

Comment: Elements can be dragged onto the canvas and then have certain attributes altered (fill colour, stroke colour, opacity, radius etc). They have default attributes which can be changed. These functions must be fired when one of the attribute types is changed I assume. The variable cannot store events if I am correct? so the variable stores a reference to the href which contains the colour I wish to manipulate, I bind that to an event to monitor when that particular colour has been clicked and this hopefully updates the selected object(s) on the canvas. At least that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Could you post the link to the page you are doing this on? It’s rather difficult to judge from the snippet you included in the question…

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that, the code is hosted internally and I don't think the company would be happy or allow me to deploy everything externally.

Comment: OK, then back to my original question: when is the code in your question run (specify the event[s], please: load, click, whatever). Also, get rid of the nested jQuery selectors – the way your code stands, your variable assignments are jQuery DOM objects already, you can `bind` to them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something that is working:

```
$('#mainToolFill div.toolPopup a.color15').bind('click',function() {
        $selectedElems.attr('fill-opacity','0');
});

$('#mainToolFill div.toolPopup a:not(".color15")').bind('click',function() {
        $selectedElems.removeAttr('fill-opacity');
});
```

The only issue with this is that it might be expensive, fill-opacity is only added once color15 has been selected, however any other colour routinely strips out the fill-opacity attribute, even though it doesn't exist (apart from in the case of colour15).